# Is it possible to show subversion log in mediawiki page?

Tags: svn, mediawiki

In my release notes I'm interested of showing the log of the committed svn revisions since the last release.

I'm looking to show this log in a Mediawiki page.

I know that there are several extensions for svn integration:

[SVN Integration](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSVNIntegration) - This only shows information about a certain file.

[Subversion Changes](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSubversionChanges) - This doesn't work out of the box.

I'm using Mediawiki 1.22.2

Do you know any other option?

Comment: Is creating your own extension an option?

Comment: Yes it is, but I'd rather use an existing one. I'm not too familiar with extension programming.

Answer (score 0):

What we have used (also on MediaWiki.org) is a web interface to the repository which provides RSS feeds and then the [RSS extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:RSS) to embed the feed on wiki pages.